# VS 2010: Is there a workaround for the administrator requirement?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-7

Aside from running as a administrator, is there any workaround for this requirement?

> xxx.vbproj : error  : The Web
>   Application Project XXX is configured
>   to use IIS. To access local IIS Web
>   sites, you must install the following
>   IIS components:
>
> In addition, you must run Visual
>   Studio in the context of an
>   administrator account.

Comment: I'd think you'd just need to give yourself the specific rights needed to debug against IIS.  Not sure what they are; might be a bit hard to configure which is why they just tell you to run as admin.  Or, you might be able to run as admin once, at which time changes will be made, and then you'll be able to run under your normal account.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want to run as an administrator, then host using the Developer Web Server (Cassini) rather than IIS.

Answer (score 1):

One option - though not recommended by Microsoft - is to turn off User Account Control (UAC):

> **[Disable User Account Control (UAC) in Windows 7](http://www.iishacks.com/index.php/2009/01/)**

Comment: I'm trying to avoid that because I need to feel my user's UAC pain. Plus it gives me an excuse to not run a virus scanner.

Answer (score 0):

You can active Administrator account and use that account you never get this issue. you can find this post which also works in windws7.

http://knowledgebaseworld.blogspot.com/2009/05/how-to-login-as-administrator-in.html

[imran](http://knowledgebaseworld.blogspot.com)

Answer (score 0):

You need to open your Visual Studio as a administrator (Right click o)

Comment: Did you read what he said, "aside from running as a administrator."